# How to tell if I'm actually in a symlink location from command line?

Tags: shell, symlink, cd-command, working-directory

Suppose I have a folder:

```
cd /home/cpm135/public_html
```

and make a symbolic link

```
ln -s /var/lib/class .
```

Later, I'm in that directory:

```
cd /home/cpm135/public_html/class
```

The `pwd` is going to tell me I'm in `/home/cpm135/public_html/class`

Is there any way to know that I'm "really" in `/var/lib/class` ?  Thanks

Comment: Related: [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/23408).

Comment: Some shells don't actually allow you to be inside a symlink. For example, the `fish` shell automatically resolves the symlink when you `cd` into it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Depending on how your `pwd` command is configured, it may default to showing the *logical* working directory (output by `pwd -L`) which would show the symlink location, or the *physical* working directory (output by `pwd -P`) which ignores the symlink and shows the "real" directory.

For complete information you can do

```
file "$(pwd -L)"
```

Inside a symlink, this will return

```
/path/of/symlink: symbolic link to /path/of/real/directory
```

Comment: yes, the `-P` flag was what I needed.  Thanks

Comment: To also answer the question in the title, just use `test "$(pwd -L)" = "$(pwd -P)" && echo No symlinks` (or replace `&& echo No symlinks` with `|| echo Symlinks`).

Comment: This answers the question perfectly without the need to echo. If the question was 'How do I display a message if I'm in a symlinked directory?" then echo would be required.

Comment: `file "$(pwd)"` only works if the symlink is the last directory component.  It doesn't detect the OP's symlink when CDed to `/home/cpm135/public_html/class/foo/bar`.  I'm not aware of anything that prints info for all the symlinks in a pathname, but you can also use `realpath .`, which I think is equivalent to `pwd -P`

Answer (score 17):

Note that `pwd` is actually a shell built-in. Depending on your shell and its configuration, results may change. For a more portable solution, you should use `/bin/pwd`. Snippet from manual page:

```
NAME
       pwd - print name of current/working directory

SYNOPSIS
       pwd [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print the full filename of the current working directory.

       -L, --logical
              use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks

       -P, --physical
              avoid all symlinks

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

       If no option is specified, -P is assumed.

       NOTE:  your  shell  may  have  its  own  version of pwd, which usually supersedes the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation for
       details about the options it supports.
```

In general, you can resolve the full canonical path of any file/directory using `readlink -f`. `readlink -f .` works similar to `pwd -P`.

Comment: Although I've learnt the hard way that `readlink -f` is not available on all Unices (e.g. not available on OS-X)

Answer (score 3):

You really are in `/home/cpm135/public_html/class` -- that's the only correct answer to the question of "what's my current working directory".

When you refer to `/var/lib/class` ... that's not really about where you are, but more about *what path you used to get there*.

When you run `/bin/pwd`, it figures out your current working directory by looking at the . and .. directories (the ones listed at the top of `ls -la`), working out which directory in .. matches up with . and then working backwards until .. and . refer to the same directory.  Once it's done all that, it knows what your current working directory is.

When you run the `pwd` shell built-in, it doesn't follow this procedure (though it might do some of it if needed) -- instead, it remembers the path that you took to get here. So each time you do a `cd` command, your shell remembers that as part of the path to get where you are now, and `pwd` prints out what it has calculated based on all the `cd` commands you've done -- which may or may not be your actual working directory.

Things can get really weird when you do a `ln -s . foo` and keep `cd`ing into foo -- `/bin/pwd` will say you're still in the same directory, but the shell builtin `pwd` will say you're in `/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo` -- even though no such directory even really exists.  (That said -- you probably *can* `cd` into it.)

Another source of confusion there is if directories are renamed.  `/bin/pwd` will then pick up on the change immediately, but the built-in `pwd` won't until you do something that tells it that the old directory name doesn't matter.

Comment: You're not answering the question, you're dismissing it.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question *directly*, I think it's a useful post for understanding the difference between the shell's `pwd` builtin and `/bin/pwd` and explaining how the stand-alone version provides more useful information (which can answer the original question).

Comment: These differences all boil down to the `-P` and `-L` options mentioned by other answers. In short, some implementations default to one, some to the other. On the Centos system I have to hand, bash's builtin is defaulting to logical, and `/bin/pwd` is defaulting to physical, but both accept both command-line options and agree on the result when they are given.

Comment: The question is based on an incorrect premise -- 'is there any way to know that I'm "really" in /var/lib/class?'

That said ... by explaining what that really means, it helps him understand what he's really looking for.

The pwd -P and -L options had already been mentioned ...

Comment: **You have your argument backwards.  `ls ..` will show the contents of `/var/lib`, not `/home/cpm135/public_html`.** `cd ..` is special: the shell does special tracking of "how you got there" and doesn't actually make a `chdir("..")` system call.  As far as the kernel is concerned, your shell's current working directory (`/proc/self/cwd`) is just a mountpoint:inode pair. It's like an open file descriptor on the directory, which is why renaming the directory doesn't break your shell.  (`cd .` to update the shell's `$PWD` variable).  You're making a useful point, so I'd upvote this when fixed

Comment: @IMSoP: `/bin/pwd -L` just prints the `$PWD` environment variable.  Without that, there's no way for a process to figure out its "logical" current working directory, because that isn't a real thing.  It doesn't affect what you get from relative paths that start with `../`, for example.  `strace /bin/pwd -P` (the default) just makes a [`getcwd(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) system call.  It doesn't trace up the `..` links itself listing the directories to find matching inode numbers.  It would be possible for the kernel to track "logical" paths, but it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes This answer talks about `/bin/pwd` and the shell doing different things, but other answers point out that both implementations have 2 modes, just different defaults. So if there really is a different algorithm used by the shell (which shell?) which mode is it for? Are there 3 different algorithms here, one for `-L` and two different ways of implementing `-P`? And when does it make a difference? I just tested the example given of `ln -s . foo`, and `/bin/pwd` and bash's builtin agree on the answer in both modes, as long as you specify the option rather than relying on the default.

Comment: @IMSoP: AFAIK, nothing except shells and `/bin/pwd` look at the `$PWD` environment variable.  IDK why `/bin/pwd` even has a `-L` option, except maybe for compatibility with the shell built-in.  Unless checking `$PWD` is starting to catch on for use in file-selectors or something by programs started from the shell, it's still meaningless outside the shell.  (But a child shell will inherit it, so it makes sense to have it in the environment).

Comment: @IMSoP:   no, I don't think there are multiple ways of implementing `-P`.  They probably all call the POSIX `getcwd()` function, which (on Linux at least) is equivalent to traversing the `..` links up to `/` and checking finding the directory you came from in each higher directory, but much more efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes Why does it have the option? For predictability: you need to be able to know that `pwd` will behave a certain way, regardless of whether it resolves to the shell implementation or the binary. So I guess *historically*, shell built-ins worked one way, and binaries the other, and then they standardised to both include both modes. I stand by my comment that *as currently implemented*, it's more useful to talk about the two modes and which is the default than to assert that there is a fundamental difference in how the shell built-in works.

Comment: @IMSoP: I never asserted that.  I just said that dougmc has it backwards, and the `pwd -P` path is the closest to the "correct" answer to where you are.  (But really, your cwd doesn't have to have a name, e.g. if it's an unlinked directory.  It still has an inode-number though, which is what the kernel really tracks).

Comment: @IMSoP: I just checked, [POSIX requires the `pwd` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/pwd.html) to support `-P` and `-L` (use `$PWD` if it refers to the current directory and is canonical).  Other than from a shell or shell script, it doesn't really make sense to run `pwd`, so I didn't see much of a use-case for it (and didn't realize the `-L` and `-P` options were standardized).  But obviously since POSIX requires it, the coreutils implementation needs to do it so it can support use-cases like perl backticks or whatever.

Comment: I don't have it backwards -- but yes, I was referring to the default usage of /bin/pwd and the default shell built-in pwd, which do indeed have different defaults (at least for most shells, regarding the shell version.)

But yes, "pwd -P" would give a more "fundamental" answer than "pwd -L"


I also really wasn't trying to be Linux specific ... this question and similar ones have been asked for longer than Linux has been around.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are asking if there is to show actual path of the current working directory. Well, there is with python and `os.getcwd()` function

What you see below is a small test from within "VirtualBox VMs" directory located in my home directory. In reality, it's a symlink to a different directory located on different hard drive, mounted at `/mnt/HDD`.

```
bash-4.3$ file "$(pwd)"
/home/xieerqi/VirtualBox VMs: symbolic link to /mnt/HDD/VirtualBox VMs/
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import os; print os.getcwd()'
/mnt/HDD/VirtualBox VMs
```

As you can see, python's `os.getcwd()` resolves the real path of the directory, not the path of symlink.